# How to make mongodb service not start automatically in ubuntu 15.10 desktop?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, runlevel

I installed `mongodb` by `Ubuntu Software Center` in `ubuntu 15.10 desktop`. `Service Mongodb` starts automatically every time when I boot my laptop. Because it is not in the server edition os, so I want to  start or stop the service manually, like `sudo sevice mongodb start/stop`.

I've tied to comment `# start on runlevel [2345]` in `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`, and remove all `*mongo*` from all `/etc/rc*.d/`.
The service still starts automatically.

So, please help me.

Comment: same question: can't start my own mongod service after start of ubuntu 14.04 because: "ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017" | where to stop autostart of mongod? how to stop service, I know

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sudo update-rc.d mongodb disable
```

This should work for Ubuntu 16.04. Not sure if 15.10 was still using upstart or not.

For more information, the same question [has been asked over AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677066/how-can-i-stop-mongodb-from-starting-on-system-boot), check the other answers there for more information.